# How to see if Dialogue ended in Godot Dialogue Manager by Nathan Hoad

Tags: dialog, godot

I want to take away the ability to move during Dialogue,but i cant find a method nor something else, that tells me if the Dialogue was exited to reactivate the ability to move. Like said in the title im working with the Godot Dialogue Manager by Nathan Hoad. Im quite the beginner so the solution might be obvious

I tried looking through the Dialogue Managers Methods but couldnt find anything

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help you or not since its been 28 days without anyone answering.

I just started developing with Godot as well and thought of similar thing as you.

I found the Tutorial also by Nathan Hoad which may help you in some part. Just a heads up, certain video may not have the things you are looking for so if you plan on adding more things be sure to check his other video and other content creator video and get creative with your solution :D. If you are making a 3D game i really recommend FinePointCGI Horror game tutorial.

This is the link to this video i mentioned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKQ_s5tl4dI (Somewhere on 2:04)

**Solution summary**

1. My approach on this is that would create a global boolean variable , so when player interact with the interacted object, this variable becomes true/false (depending on your coding style). This part would be an if/else statement
2. When entered the if/else statement, the global boolean variable will update to false/true **AND** run the DialogueManager code to run the dialogue
3. In terms of player movement, you have to get creative. Use the global boolean variable to restrict your player movement, maybe make it so that your player movement speed would be 0.
4. To make sure that your player would be able to move again, update the global boolean variable inside of balloon.gd

**Additional**
I also found that you can spam the interact button and the interact would keep piling up, so this approach would also help on that.

*Code inside balloon.gd*

```
var dialogue_line: DialogueLine:
    set(next_dialogue_line):
        if next_dialogue_line == null:
            globalVariable.globalBoolean= false
            #globalVariable is the name of autoload node script given. Refer the next code section i gave to see how to create this variable
            #globalBoolean is the name of the variable inside the autoload script
        
       #rest of the code that already exist
```

*Code inside global variable script (autoload script)*

```
extends Node

var globalBoolean: bool = false
#To create this, go to Project Settings>Autoload>Create this script and add path, and then name the Node
```

*Code inside the object player interacts with*

```
func someInteractionFunction():
    if not globalVariable.globalBoolean: #not depends on your coding style
            globalVariable.globalBoolean = true
            DialogueManager.show_dialogue_balloon(Dialogue_Resource,dialogueStart) #putting this here helps with player spamming interaction button
```